# JAXB: two xsd with two complextype with the same name

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, xjc, maven-jaxb2-plugin

This is my first xsd (`catalegs-schema.xsd`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="request" type="SearchRequestType"/>

  <xs:complexType name="SearchRequestType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="tableName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="oid" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="owner" type="OwnerType"/>
      <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="term" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="referenceDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="startIndex" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="pageSize" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="OwnerType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ownerType" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="ownerCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  
</xs:schema>
```

My second xsd (`oid-schema.xml`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="request" type="SearchRequestType"/>

  <xs:complexType name="SearchRequestType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="oid" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="referenceDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="startIndex" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="pageSize" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

As you can see, there are defined two `SearchRequestType` complexType.

I'm using this `bindings.xml` file:

```xml
<jaxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox xjc"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" 
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
    
    version="2.1">
    
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="oid-schema.xsd">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="cat.catsalut.hes.mpi.hazelcast.loader.domain.serveiterritorial.oid"/>
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='SearchRequestType']">
            <jaxb:class name="attemptdatap"/>
            <annox:annotate>@lombok.Builder</annox:annotate>
            <annox:annotate>@lombok.NoArgsConstructor</annox:annotate>
            <annox:annotate>@lombok.AllArgsConstructor</annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="catalegs-schema.xsd">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="cat.catsalut.hes.mpi.hazelcast.loader.domain.serveiterritorial.catalegs"/>
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='SearchRequestType']">
            <annox:annotate>@lombok.Builder</annox:annotate>
            <annox:annotate>@lombok.NoArgsConstructor</annox:annotate>
            <annox:annotate>@lombok.AllArgsConstructor</annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='OwnerType']">
            <annox:annotate>@lombok.Builder</annox:annotate>
            <annox:annotate>@lombok.NoArgsConstructor</annox:annotate>
            <annox:annotate>@lombok.AllArgsConstructor</annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

I'm getting this message:

```
Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/home/jeusdi/projects/salut/mpi/hes-mpi-hazelcast-loader-service/xsd/servei-territorial/merge/catalegs-schema.xsd{4,56}].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: 'request' is already defined
```

Complete output:

```
$ ~/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.201-oracle/bin/xjc -verbose -xmlschema xsd/servei-territorial/merge/catalegs-schema.xsd -xmlschema xsd/servei-territorial/merge/oid-schema.xsd -b xsd/servei-territorial/merge/bindings.xjb -extension -npa -no-header           
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] Unsupported binding namespace "". Perhaps you meant "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"?
  line 2 of file:/home/jeusdi/projects/salut/mpi/hes-mpi-hazelcast-loader-service/xsd/servei-territorial/merge/catalegs-schema.xsd

[ERROR] Unsupported binding namespace "http://annox.dev.java.net". Perhaps you meant "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"?
  line 2 of file:/home/jeusdi/projects/salut/mpi/hes-mpi-hazelcast-loader-service/xsd/servei-territorial/merge/catalegs-schema.xsd

[ERROR] Unsupported binding namespace "http://annox.dev.java.net". Perhaps you meant "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"?
  line 2 of file:/home/jeusdi/projects/salut/mpi/hes-mpi-hazelcast-loader-service/xsd/servei-territorial/merge/oid-schema.xsd

[ERROR] 'request' is already defined
  line 4 of file:/home/jeusdi/projects/salut/mpi/hes-mpi-hazelcast-loader-service/xsd/servei-territorial/merge/oid-schema.xsd

[ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here
  line 4 of file:/home/jeusdi/projects/salut/mpi/hes-mpi-hazelcast-loader-service/xsd/servei-territorial/merge/catalegs-schema.xsd

[ERROR] 'SearchRequestType' is already defined
  line 15 of file:/home/jeusdi/projects/salut/mpi/hes-mpi-hazelcast-loader-service/xsd/servei-territorial/merge/oid-schema.xsd

[ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here
  line 6 of file:/home/jeusdi/projects/salut/mpi/hes-mpi-hazelcast-loader-service/xsd/servei-territorial/merge/catalegs-schema.xsd

Failed to parse a schema.
```

Any ideas about how to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you import xml schema's with objects which have the same names and no unique namespace into your project they will added to the same project namespace and then you have duplicate definitions of objects.

this can be resolved by adding xml namespaces in the xml schema's making them unique or importing the xml schema's into different namespaces in your project.

by the looks of your xml schema layout you also could change the xml schemas. if you add a third schema where you define the base of the complextype

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
      <xs:complexType name="SearchRequestType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="oid" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="referenceDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="startIndex" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="pageSize" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

then include (and extend) this base into your other xml schemas

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:include schemaLocation="srtype.xsd" />
  <xs:element name="request" type="SearchRequestType"/>
</xs:schema>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="srtype.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="request" type="extSearchRequestType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="extSearchRequestType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="SearchRequestType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="tableName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element name="owner" type="OwnerType"/>
                    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xs:element name="term" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="OwnerType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ownerType" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="ownerCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

then it should import without a problem.

Comment: will this fix the OP's issue? I have a pretty similar issue, and my xsd's are pretty much structured as per your answer, however, when i try to use jaxb to generate the classes i always get a "'request' is already defined" type error. 

And, indeed, even in your answer there are two request elements defined. Did you have to use some special binding to get this to work? Any insight would be great! Thanks!

Comment: As long as all the xsd's are sharing the same namespace you cannot declare elements with the same name even if they are in different files. the above example only shows how to extract a type from a file so you do not have to define it multiple times and how to use it and extend it with additional content. to make this work you should add to all the example files unique namespaces.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification - i thought that was the case, but wanted to make sure that there wasnt some "magic" i was missing to get the above example working without changing namespaces (which isnt an option for me) - thanks again!